# adobe air swf file error in browser

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs3

my fla file setting

version: adobe air 1.0
actionscript 3.0

i able to compile without problem and when i load the swf file in browser, if my actionscript included this line "**import flash.filesystem.File**". My flash just show up "**blank**" . no error in flashlog. if i removed this line, my swf file able to run. what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flash.filesystem.File package is only available if you compile the fla to an AIR-file. You can not read and write files in browser applications.

Comment: if i compile to air file, can it be embeded on page ,just like swf file?

Comment: If you want to embed in HTML, you should compile to swf.

Comment: i already compiled to swf and as stated in my configuration above, i am using adobe air.  do you know wy i get the blank?

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Compiling to swf but using AIR? not possible. Compiling to AIR produces an SWF but it is only usable in an AIR application. What IDE are you using? Flex, FlashDevelop, Flash etc?